# solaris modular debugger - mdb - examples

Tags: debugging, solaris

I'm looking for user-friendly manual for Solaris debugger - `mdb`, where I can find examples of examining stack. I tried searching for an answer for a while, but all I could find was official manual and only few private pages with not so much information.

Comment: Solaris debugger??  Solaris is an operating system...

Comment: Do you mean operating systems don't need debuggers ?

Answer (score 6):

Some more resources:

- [mdb(1) background, intro, and cheatsheet - Jonathan Adam's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/jwadams/entry/an_mdb_1_cheat_sheet)
- [Learn mdb in 30 minutes - Code Complete blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/comand/entry/learn_mdb_in_30_minutes)
- [Modular Debugger (mdb) OpenSolaris community group](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+mdb/WebHome)
- [Solaris Performance and Tools: DTrace and MDB Techniques for Solaris 10 and OpenSolaris](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131568191)